# Add a value to a cell using textbox if it is empty

Tags: vba, excel

I have a userform in which there are many textboxes and one combobox,  the value of the combobox comes from the Excel sheet. What I want is If the cell A,F,J,K are empty I want them to be manually entered through the textbox if available then they should be seen in the textbox.Please find code.

```
Private Sub cbox5_Change()
    Dim r As Long
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Set wks = Worksheets("Sheet2")
    r = cbox5.ListIndex + 2
    On Error Resume Next
    If wks.Cells(r, "R") = "" Then
        txt8.Value = wks.Cells(r, "N")
    Else
        txt8.Value = wks.Cells(r, "R")
    End If
    txt10.Value = wks.Cells(r, "F")
    txt11.Value = wks.Cells(r, "A")
    txt16.Value = wks.Cells(r, "J")
    txt17.Value = wks.Cells(r, "K")
    If cbox5.Value = "" Then
        Sheets("Sheet2").Select
        Range("A65536").Select
        Selection.End(xlUp).Select
        ActiveCell.Offset(1).Select
        Me.txt8.Value = ""
        Me.txt9.Value = ""
        Me.txt10.Value = ""
        Me.txt11.Value = ""
        Me.txt15.Value = ""
        Me.txt16.Value = ""
    End If
End Sub
```

Also I am unable to see the value in combobox until the userform is closed and opened again. Can anyone let me know what might be causing this problem? Where do I need to change the code?

I am unable to get this code to work:

```
If wks.Cells(r, "D") = "" Then
    wks.Cells(r, "D").Value = Me.txt9.Value
Else
    txt9.Value = wks.Cells(r, "D")
End If
```

Comment: Under the presumption that your ComboBox is `cbox5`, I don't see anywhere in this code that you're assigning anything to it. Therefore, there's no reason for the value of the ComboBox to change.

Comment: @Freeman this is the code for cbox5,
        'With Worksheets("Sheet2")
        cbox5.List = .Range("I2:I150" & .Range("I" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value
End With'

Comment: It's very difficult to read code in the comments. Edit your original post, put that in the appropriate location and detail any error messages you may be getting and what line they're appearing on.

Comment: Just for more clarification If wks.Cells(r, "D") = "" then I want the value to be added through textbox txt8. how do I do that??

Comment: I'd recommend solving one issue at a time.

Comment: @FreeMan What do I need to add to the above code??

Comment: I believe I've addressed the "changes to combobox don't show" issue, below. In your original question, you say "What I want is if the cell is empty add value to the cell.". Please edit your OP to be more specific about which cell is empty, where the value comes from, and which cell it's to be added to.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you're populating the combobox in the `OnChange` event for the combobox. Your user will not be able to select anything from `cbox5` because there is nothing in it, so it will never be triggered. You need to put the code to populate the combobox in the `Initialize` or `Activate` events.

Comment: the code was previously in the Userform_Initialize event but the problem was eventhough there was some data in the I cell I had to close and reopen the Userform Once again.